# OpenXml Word Footnotes

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to iterate through a Word document and extract the footnotes out of it, with a reference to where they belong in the paragraph.
I'm not sure how to do this.

I saw that in order to get all the footnotes I can do something like this:

```
FootnotesPart footnotesPart = doc.MainDocumentPart.FootnotesPart;
if (footnotesPart != null)
{
    IEnumerable<Footnote> footnotes = footnotesPart.Footnotes.Elements<Footnote>();

    foreach (var footnote in footnotes)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to know where each footnote belongs in the paragraph.
I want, for instance, to take a footnote, and put it in brackets inside the text where it was a footnote before.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to locate the `FootnoteReference` element with the same Id as the `FootNote`. This will give you the `Run` element, where the footnote is located.

Sample code:

```
FootnotesPart footnotesPart = doc.MainDocumentPart.FootnotesPart;
if (footnotesPart != null)
{
    var footnotes = footnotesPart.Footnotes.Elements<Footnote>();
    var references = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FootnoteReference>().ToArray();
    foreach (var footnote in footnotes)
    {
        long id = footnote.Id;
        var reference = references.Where(fr => (long)fr.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (reference != null)
        {
            Run run = reference.Parent as Run;
            reference.Remove();
            var fnText = string.Join("", footnote.Descendants<Run>().SelectMany(r => r.Elements<Text>()).Select(t => t.Text)).Trim();
            run.Parent.InsertAfter(new Run(new Text("(" + fnText + ")")), run);
        }
    }
}
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
doc.Close();
```